# Routing Links to parent routes in Ember JS

Tags: ember.js, routes

In my application I have the following route setup

```
Orders.Router.map ->
  @resource "orders", path: '/', ->
    @route 'new'
    @route 'show', path: ':order_id'
    @resource 'items', path: ':order_id/items', ->
        @route 'new'

class Orders.ItemsNewRoute extends Ember.Route
  model: (params) ->
    Orders.Order.find params.order_id
```

Within my `items.new` route, I would like to have a link back to `orders.show` and am unable to find the best way of going about this.

I cannot find a way to bind my parameter from my URL to the `linkTo` helper. What would be the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 0):

Ryan,

I'm not 100% sure I understand what your question is but linkTo is very simple to use.

```
{{#linkTo "orders.show" controller.content}}Show My Order{{/linkTo}}
```

The above code will send you to the orders.show route with the model being the content of your controller.

Steve

Comment: That didn't seem to work. That is sending me to a route with `#/undefined`

I updated the post to also show my route.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is the best way to go about this, but I was able to mess about with the router a bit to make it more like this:

```
Orders.Router.map ->
  @resource "orders", path: '/', ->
    @route 'new'
    @route 'show', path: ':order_id'
    @resource 'items', path: ':order_id/items/new'

class Orders.OrdersRoute extends Ember.Route
  model: ->
    return Orders.Order.find()

class Orders.OrdersIndexRoute extends Ember.Route
  model: ->
    return Orders.Order.find()

class Orders.ItemsRoute extends Ember.Route
  model: (params)->
    return Orders.Item.createRecord
      order: Orders.Order.find params.order_id
```

Then in my template I reference `{{#linkTo 'orders.show' order}}`

It seems that it was not able to grab a reference from the original `:order_id` wildcard.